# Php, header, readfile и nokia 6300

Tags: header, php, yii

Доброго времени суток знатоки!

Появилась необходимость поработать со старыми мобилками, а конкретно nokia 6300. Суть в том, что в ней, перейдя по ссылке на сайт, там можно скачать какой-то контент, допустим, картинку. Воспользовался я стандартным способом. А именно:

```
        $file = 'http://some_url/'.$model->CFile_name;
        if (ob_get_level()) {
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');           
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        readfile($file);
```

На ноуте и на смартфонах все отдает как надо, а вот на той мобилке возвращает длиннющий набор каракуль. К сожалению, в эпоху тех телефонов, я еще даже не думал изучать web, поэтому не знаю, как с ними работать. Гугл ничего не дал по этому поводу. Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобным? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее, вот этот код должен решить вашу проблему:

```
$file = 'http://some_url/'.$model->CFile_name;

/**
 * Первая строчка означает: не пытайся открыть файл - просто сохраняй  
 */
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
```

---

**Update:**
Поскольку явный костыль не заработал, можно попробовать этот вариант:

```
$file = 'http://some_url/'.$model->CFile_name;

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

Comment: Да, помогло. Спасибо большое! Правда, появился еще один нюанс. С картинками все нормально, но так же клиент еще может скачивать темы, игры, музыку и видео. Я попытался качнуть темы с расширением utz, а он после скачивания сам сменил его на ext и не открывает. Я так понимаю, это расширение сама система ставит, так как не может распознать дефолтное?

Comment: Спасибо большое, но, к сожалению, тоже не заработал. Сначала вообще отказался скачивать файл, а когда я убрал строку header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); - заработал. Что интересно, скачал одну тему и одну песню. В обоих случаях расширение было ext, но песню сотовый начал проигрывать, а вот тему не открыл.

Comment: @тигрище, похоже, вам ничего не остается, кроме как корректно указыать MIME-type для всех типов контента, которые сохраняются нормально на телефоне, а для картинок использовать первый хак.

Comment: Похоже на то. Спасибо большое за помощь!